# How I get the output like output string?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this issue in so many times.
But I can't understand how to get numeric value respected ASCII character.

By following this steps:

1. Replace the character in even position with their corresponding
   ASCII value
2. Reverse the string using StringBuilder.

Input string:--->

```
?85O89*69R65*87O104*33I104
```

Output should be like this:--->

```
?uoy*era*woH*!iH
```

How I get the output In java?

Comment: What does the input represent?

Comment: Could you please more comprehend this problem by adding some statement and more simple examples. That'd be really helpful

Comment: @Alex I might be wrong, but the first thing to do on the input `String` is to call `toLowerCase()` and then parse the integers to characters via ASCII. Or something like that.

Comment: Do you need other clarifications?

Comment: When you said the reverse, do you mean, change Uppercase to lowercase, lowercase to uppercase. Since on the ASCII table, the char at position 85 is "U" unppercase. And also, is ever even position are separated with char that are not numbers?(eg: ?85O89* are all separated by either "?", "O", or "*")

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the others I think this is actually an interesting question, that a newbie may find difficult to understand.

Given the string

```
?85O89*69R65*87O104*33I104
```

We see there is repetitive pattern, a character + a numeric value. We have then

```
?85
O89
*69
R65
*87
O104
*33
I104
```

Based on the proposed output we understand the number represents an [ASCII codepoint](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html).
Also we see that the case of each character is reversed.

Thus, we may write the following code.

```
final String value = "?85O89*69R65*87O104*33I104";
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// We split the string based on the \w(\d+) pattern, "reversed"
final String[] parts = value.split("(?=([^\\d]+))");

for (final String s : parts) {
   // For each character we must reverse its case
   // The first symbol is already in a presentable form
   final char c = s.charAt(0);
   sb.append(Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toLowerCase(c) : Character.toUpperCase(c));

   // The remaining part represents an ASCII symbol in decimal form
   final int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
   final String str = new String(Character.toChars(codePoint));
   sb.append(Character.isUpperCase(codePoint) ? str.toLowerCase() : str.toUpperCase());
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

Which will correctly print

```
?uoy*era*woH*!iH
```

Answer (score 0):

The input string seems to be using `*` as "word" delimiters which should be kept in the output.

A "word" contains 3 characters, the first and the last characters are displayed as ASCII codes in the encoded string.

When decoding a word, the case of the letter character has to be inverted: lower -> upper, upper -> lower.

That being said, the following implementation may be as follows:

```java
static Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(.)(\\d+)");

public static String decode(String str) {
    return Arrays
        .stream(str.split("((?<=[*!\\?])|(?=[*!\\?]))"))
        .map(s -> s.matches(WORD.pattern()) ? decodeWord(s) : s)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}

private static String decodeWord(String word) {
    Matcher match = WORD.matcher(word);
    if (match.find()) {
        return new StringBuilder()
            .append(decodeChar((char)(Integer.parseInt(match.group(1)))))
            .append(decodeChar(match.group(2).charAt(0)))
            .append(decodeChar((char)(Integer.parseInt(match.group(3)))))
            .toString();
    }
    return ""; 
}

static char decodeChar(char c) {
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        return Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toLowerCase(c) : Character.toUpperCase(c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(decode("?85O89*69R65*87O104*33I104"));
```

Output:

```
?uoy*era*woH*!iH
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said, and base on the string you give, I'm ASSUMING that every even position is between(not include the ending) two non-numbers.

```
    public static String perform(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        
        String dump = "";//dump string
        for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++) {//Read the string char by char
            int ascii = (int) str.charAt(i);//work with ASCII
            
            if(ascii - '0' < 0 || ascii - '0' > 9) {//check if ascii is a non-number
                
                if(dump.length() != 0) {//can dump
                    int c = Integer.parseInt(dump);
                    
                    if(c >= 65 && c <= 90) {//uppercase to lowercase
                        sb.append((char) (c - 'A' + 'a'));
                    }
                    
                    if(c >= 97 && c <= 122) {//lowercase to uppercase
                        sb.append((char) (c - 'a' + 'A'));
                    }
                    dump = "";//clear
                }
                
                if(ascii < 65 || (ascii > 90 && ascii < 97) || ascii > 122) {//not a letter
                    sb.append(str.charAt(i));
                }else {//is a letter
                    if(ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90) {//uppercase to lowercase
                        sb.append((char) (ascii - 'A' + 'a'));
                    }
                    
                    if(ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122) {//lowercase to uppercase
                        sb.append((char) (ascii - 'a' + 'A'));
                    }
                }
                
            }else {// Is number
                dump += str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        
        if(dump.length() != 0) {
            int c = Integer.parseInt(dump);
            
            if(c >= 65 && c <= 90) {//uppercase to lowercase
                sb.append((char) (c - 'A' + 'a'));
            }
            
            if(c >= 97 && c <= 122) {//lowercase to uppercase
                sb.append((char) (c - 'a' + 'A'));
            }
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
```